# Mongoose get documents that are in multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema called `Movie` and a schema called `User`, User's schema is like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    movies:[{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}],
    password:{type:String, required:true},
    username:{type:String, unique:true, required:true},
    wishlist:[{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}],
    seen:[{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}],
    liked:[{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}],
    disliked:[{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}]
});
```

I want to query the movies that are both in `movies` and in `liked` or are in `movies` and not in `seen`. For now I'm doing this with having multiple for loops over all the data in **Node.js** but it seems wrong, so I was wondering is there any way to do this in mongoose?

Comment: You can try using the aggregate with $match , and for checking various conditions inside $match you can have  $and and $or operators where you can check for various conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the query operators `$and`, `$in` and `$nin` like this:

```
User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    Movie.find({
        $and: [{
            '_id': {$in: user.movies},
            '_id': {$in: user.liked},
            '_id': {$nin: user.seen}
        }]
    })
        .limit(20)
        .populate(populateQuery)
        .exec(function (err, movies) {
            //movies is the movies that are both in movies and liked and are not in seen
            res.send(movies);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mongoose's populate function. If I understood your question correctly then try out this solution:

```
var populateQuery = [{path: 'movies'}, {path: 'liked'}]
User.find({'_id': id}).populate(populateQuery).execPopulate()
```

You can try playing with the query to get results you need.

[Mongoose populate docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I want to get the movies that are both in movies and liked, so the query of `find` is what I'm looking for not the population part

Comment: Have you tried the code i wrote? Isn't it working for your purposes?

Comment: I found the solution, let me post it as an answer and you'll see what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyways

Comment: you can check out the answer now